# Single dimensional array becomes multidimensional after submit

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, php-7.3

I have done my research and cannot find an answer so now I'm here to seek out professionals' advice.

I have a query which returns an array in model:

```
$sql = "SalesList ";
$sql = $sql."'".$current_company_code."', ";  
$sql = $sql."'".trim($current_user_id)."', "; 
$sql = $sql."'".$as_date."', ";  
$sql = $sql.$language_no; 

$DB=$this->load->database($current_database,TRUE);
$query = $DB->query($sql); 

return $query->result();
```

In controller: I passed the result to $data['sales_list'] and load to view

```
$data['sales_list'] = $this->SalesList->GetSalesList($current_database,$current_company_code,$current_user_id,date('Y-m-d 23:59:59'),$language_no);
$this->load->view('Sales_Record', $data);
```

In view:

```
  <?php foreach ($sales_list as $record): ?>
         <input type="hidden" name="sp_name_d[]" id="sp_name_d[]" value="<?php echo set_value('sp_name_d[]',trim($record->sp_name));?>"/>                      
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Problem:
Upon submit, the same coding (which presents no issue on first load) prompted the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Line Number: 39

Array"/>
```

Line no 39 refers to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sp_name_d[]" id="sp_name_d[]" value="<?php echo set_value('sp_name_d[]',trim($record->sp_name));?>"/>
```

Help needed. Thank you.
Sincerely, blossoming programmer.

[Update] Cause of issue (Rookie mistake):
I have some codes in view that use index in set_value (for radio button reference) which leads to multidimensional array:

```
<input type="radio" name="status_d[<?php  echo $counter;?>]" id="status_d[]" value="1" <?php echo set_value('status_d['.$counter.']', '1', $record->status==1); ?> checked />
```

Solution:
in view added index in set_value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sp_name_d[]" id="sp_name_d[]" value="<?php echo set_value('sp_name_d['.$counter.']',trim($record->sp_name));?>"/>
```

Comment: ca you print the array

Comment: Yes, I use print_r to print $sales_list in view and both results (before submit and after submit) returned the same string except the latter contains the php error after print_r

Comment: trim don't work on an array , it  works on string

Comment: print set_value output  , i thinks it is returning array and you are doing echo on array  there

Comment: Rahul, yes it is returning an array which I don't understand. The first time this page loads it is not and after submit, it becomes an array

Comment: because the first time there is no input so it becomes an empty string, but after submit it is an array which remains array

Comment: Thank you for the clue to my issue. I just inspected the value on first load, it is indeed empty. At the risk of sounding dense, is there a reason as to why the same query will return empty on first load and when requery it becomes an array? No changes is done upon requery

Comment: check answer...

Comment: Thank you honestly for your answer, Rahul. Stay safe and healthy

Comment: Stay safe and healthy , your family too. Please mark as answer too , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is:
set_value() - The first time there is no input so it becomes an empty string, but after submit it is an array which remains array.

On an Fresh load of a page there is no previous input data, So everything is empty in Form When setting via set_value.